# How to check if datarow exists in datable without using primary key method

Tags: vb.net, search, datatable, datarow

I am using VB .NET and I want to check if a Datarow (Row A) from a Datatable(Table A) exists in another datatable (Table B).

I had tried using the code below:

```
TableA.Rows.Contains(RowA)
```

I got an error message stating:
"MissingPrimaryKeyException was unhandled by user code. Table does not have a primary key".

Could you suggest how can I search a datarow in a datatable without using primary key method?

Thank you.

Comment: What does the data in the row look like?  What does it mean for the row to be in both tables?  Does it mean the data is the same?  Or is the same actual DataRow object in both tables?

Comment: @Derek, the data types in DataRow consist of String and Boolean. In other words, it has a mixed columns of Boolean and String. Both TableA and TableB have the same data structures. (Both have the same columns). When I remove a specific row in TableA, I would like to perform the same task on TableB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim i As Integer = (datatable.Rows.Count - 1)
Do While (i >= 0)
    If datatable.Rows(i)("Column1") = RowA("Column1") And datatable.Rows(i)("Column2") = RowA("Column2")  Then
        datatable.Rows(i).Delete
    End If
    i = i - 1
Loop
```

You will have to change the names of the columns, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Check [row state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowstate(v=vs.110).aspx) of RowA, if it's [Detached](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.rowstate(v=vs.110).aspx), the table does not contain it.

Without primary key, I don't know how you can make it work any better than that.